# Mixed content: page at https was loaded over https but requested an insecure

Tags: nginx, flask, flask-socketio, flask-sockets

I'm using Nginx + flask-socketio + aws elb and when the URL is loaded on https I'm getting the following error message which is something related to the Nginx and socket, please help on this,

```
socket.io.min.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1477375737508'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.d.handshake @ socket.io.min.js:2
socket.io.min.js:2 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1477375737508. Failed to start loading.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look into your `.js` file, make sure that you are using the right ajax URL (`//your_site.com/handler`, instead of `http://your_site.com/handler`), for instance:

```
$.ajax({
url:'//your_site.com/handler',dataType:'json',type:'get',
success: function(data){...},
complete:function(xhr, textStatus){...}
});
```

Comment: actually i overlooked that in my js file, all the while i was hitting the bush. Alow now i'm getting "WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/socket.io/1/websocket/654646646' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500"

Comment: Maybe these links can help:

[Link 1](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/378#issuecomment-170352798)

[Link 2](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/211#issuecomment-57744925)

Answer (score 0):

Mixed Content is a security policy employed by current browsers, and its goal is to prevent leaking information fetched over "secure" HTTPS to non-secure contexts. Therefore, a site served with HTTPS must use HTTPS or other TLS-enabled protocols to fetch content.

The URI prefix for Websockets over TLS is `wss`, and for plain Websockets `ws`. At least [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85271) and [Firefox](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85271) consider `https`+`ws` mixed content, and deny such setting - therefore `wss` should be used as the URI prefix in secure/HTTPS contexts instead of `ws`.